# Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()

Tags: jquery, dom-events

So after reading a recently answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285902/mouseover-problem) i am unclear if i really understand the difference between the `mouseenter()` and `mouseover()`. The post states

**MouseOver():**

> Will fire upon entering an element and whenever any mouse movements
> occur within the element.

**MouseEnter():**

> Will fire upon entering an element.

I came up with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/1/) that uses both and they seem to be quite similar. Can someone please explain to me the difference between the two ?

I have also tried reading the JQuery definitions, both say the same thing.

> The mouseover event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer enters the element
>
> The mouseenter event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer enters the element.

Can someone please clarify with an example?

Comment: The demo in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) shows it quite well imo.

Comment: It's worth noting that mouseenter and mouseleave were proprietary events in IE only and emulated in other browsers by jQuery (they appear to now be in the spec although still not implemented in other browsers. See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You see the behavior when your target element contains child elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/7/

Each time your mouse enters or leaves a child element, `mouseover` is triggered, but not `mouseenter`.

```js
$('#my_div').bind("mouseover mouseenter", function(e) {
  var el = $("#" + e.type);
  var n = +el.text();
  el.text(++n);
});
```

```css
#my_div {
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#my_div>div {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>MouseEnter: <span id="mouseenter">0</span></div>
<div>MouseOver: <span id="mouseover">0</span></div>

<div id="my_div">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @psychobrm - No. Play with these two demos that also track the `mouseleave` event:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/232/ http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/233/  If over where the same as enter + leave, then the count for over would be the sum of the counts for enter and leave.

Comment: is there a specific reason to write `var n = + el.text();` instead of `var n = el.text();`? I am asking just for curiosity.

Comment: @FredrickGauss - I'm using the `+` operator to coerce the string returned from `el.text()` to a number.  Did I *need* to? No. In this case, the next statement that uses `n` would also coerce it to a number. So, *why* did I use it? I'm not sure... this was 2 years ago. It's a good habit. It makes my intention explicit. Probably I originally had `n + 1` before I saved, but decided to shrink my code by 2 chars and just use `++n`.  `n + 1` would *not* coerce `n` to a number, but instead would coerce `1` to a string resulting in output of, eg `0111111`.

Comment: @gilly3 - thanks for detailed explanation of your travel in the mind.

Comment: @gilly3 Good summary, but a minor improvement: "or leaves a child element" should be "or leaves a child element, given that there's a gap between the child and the parent. your fiddle has a margin/padding, and thus it's true that whenever you leave the child element you get a mouseover event, but try it with no padding/margins, and you won't get this event.

Comment: It's worth noting that similar behaviour can be observed with mouseout vs mouseleave.  The former triggers on child elements, the latter does not. See: https://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/1509/

Answer (score 21):

Though they operate the same way, however, the `mouseenter` event only **triggers when the mouse pointer enters the selected element**. The `mouseover` event is triggered **if a mouse pointer enters any child elements as well**.

Answer (score 3):

See the example code and demo at the bottom of the jquery documentation page:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

> ... mouseover fires when the pointer moves into the child element as
>   well, while mouseenter fires only when the pointer moves into the
>   bound element.

Answer (score 3):

The **mouseenter** event **differs** from **mouseover** in the way it handles **event bubbling**. The **mouseenter** event, only **triggers** its handler when the **mouse enters the element** it is bound to, **not a descendant**.
Refer: https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

The **mouseleave** event **differs** from **mouseout** in the way it handles **event bubbling**. The **mouseleave** event, only **triggers** its handler when the **mouse leaves the element** it is bound to, **not a descendant**.
Refer: https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but still no good up-to-date answer with insight imo.

As jQuery uses Javascript wording for events and handlers, *but does its own undocumented, but different interpretation of those*, let me first shed light on the difference from the pure Javascript viewpoint:

- both event pairs

  - the mouse can “jump” from outside/outer elements to inner/innermost elements when moved faster than the browser samples its position
  - any `enter/over` gets a corresponding `leave/out` (possibly late/jumpy)
  - events go to the visible element below the pointer (invisible elements can’t be target)
- `mouseenter/mouseleave`

  - **does not bubble** (event not useful for delegate handlers)
  - the event registration itself defines the area of observation and abstraction
  - works on the target area, like a park with a pond: the pond is considered part of the park
  - the event is emitted on the target/area whenever the element itself *or any descendant directly* is entered/left the first time
  - entering a descendant, moving from one descendant to another or moving back into the target does not finish/restart the `mouseenter/mouseleave` cycle (i.e. no events fire)
  - if you want to observe multiple areas with one handler, register it on each area/element or use the other event pair discussed next
  - descendants of registered areas/elements can have their own handlers, creating an independent observation area with its independent `mouseenter/mouseleave` event cycles
  - if you think about how a bubbling version of `mouseenter/mouseleave` could look like, you end up with with something like `mouseover/mouseout`
- `mouseover/mouseout`

  - **events bubble**
  - events fire whenever the element below the pointer changes

    - `mouseout` on the previously sampled element
    - followed by `mouseover` on the new element
    - the events don’t “nest”: before e.g. a child is “overed” the parent will be “out”
  - `target/relatedTarget` indicate new and previous element
  - if you want to watch different areas

    - register one handler on a common parent (or multiple parents, which together cover all elements you want to watch)
    - look for the element you are interested in between the handler element and the target element; maybe `$(event.target).closest(...)` suits your needs

Not-so-trivial `mouseover/mouseout` example:

```
$('.side-menu, .top-widget')
  .on('mouseover mouseout', event => {
    const target = event.type === 'mouseover' ? event.target : event.relatedTarget;
    const thing = $(target).closest('[data-thing]').attr('data-thing') || 'default';
    // do something with `thing`
  });
```

These days, all browsers support `mouseover/mouseout` and `mouseenter/mouseleave` natively. Nevertheless, jQuery does not register your handler to `mouseenter/mouseleave`, but silently puts them on a wrappers around `mouseover/mouseout` as the code below exposes.

The emulation is unnecessary, imperfect and a waste of CPU cycles: it filters out `mouseover/mouseout` events that a `mouseenter/mouseleave` would not get, but the `target` is messed. The real `mouseenter/mouseleave` would give the handler element as target, the emulation might indicate children of that element, i.e. whatever the `mouseover/mouseout` carried.

For that reason I do not use jQuery for those events, but e.g.:

```
$el[0].addEventListener('mouseover', e => ...);
```

```js
const list = document.getElementById('log');
const outer = document.getElementById('outer');
const $outer = $(outer);

function log(tag, event) {
  const li = list.insertBefore(document.createElement('li'), list.firstChild);
  // only jQuery handlers have originalEvent
  const e = event.originalEvent || event;
  li.append(`${tag} got ${e.type} on ${e.target.id}`);
}

outer.addEventListener('mouseenter', log.bind(null, 'JSmouseenter'));
$outer.on('mouseenter', log.bind(null, '$mouseenter'));
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

#inner {
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id=outer>
    <ul id=log>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Note: For delegate handlers never use jQuery’s “delegate handlers with selector registration”. (Reason in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741850/825924).) Use this (or similar):

```
$(parent).on("mouseover", e => {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.gold').length) {...};
});
```

instead of

```
$(parent).on("mouseover", '.gold', e => {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

This example demonstrates the difference between the **mousemove**, **mouseenter** and **mouseover** events:

https://jsfiddle.net/z8g613yd/

HTML:

```
<div onmousemove="myMoveFunction()">
    <p>onmousemove: <br> <span id="demo">Mouse over me!</span></p>
</div>

<div onmouseenter="myEnterFunction()">
    <p>onmouseenter: <br> <span id="demo2">Mouse over me!</span></p>
</div>

<div onmouseover="myOverFunction()">
    <p>onmouseover: <br> <span id="demo3">Mouse over me!</span></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

p {
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
}

p span {
    background-color: #86fcd4;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;

function myMoveFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z += 1;
}

function myEnterFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x += 1;
}

function myOverFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = y += 1;
}
```

- **`onmousemove`** : occurs every time the mouse pointer is moved over the div element.
- **`onmouseenter`** : only occurs when the mouse pointer enters the div element.
- **`onmouseover`**  :  occurs when the mouse pointer enters the div element,
  and its child elements (p and span).

Comment: somehow jsfiddle is broken saying funcitons are undefined - I just forked and moved all js to `<script>` https://jsfiddle.net/orc8empd/