# jquery .mouseover() and .mouseout() with fade

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to fade a div in with jquery when the user hovers over a parent div.

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Explore D&amp;D Creative</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/explore.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.custom.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body id="home">

        <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div id="content">

            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW -->
            <div id="top-slide">
                <div class="wrapper">

                </div>  
                <div id="select">...</div>          
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW -->



            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT TWITTER -->
            <div id="twitter-main">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
                    <span class="divider"></span>
                    <h2 class="feed">THIS IS SOME TWITTER TEXT</h2>
                    <p class="info">@DandDCreative - SOME TIME AGO</p>
                </div>            
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT TWIITER -->


        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT -->

    </body>

</html>​
```

CSS:

```
/*============================================
    CONTENT
============================================*/
#content {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-top:55px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
/*============================================
    HOME.PHP
============================================*/
#home #content #top-slide {
    background-color:#3D3B37;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select {
    height:48px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background:url(../img/home/bg-slie-select.png) repeat;
    display:none;
}

#home #content #twitter-main {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
}

#home #content #twitter-main i.icon-twitter {
    background:url(../img/common/social/twitter.png) no-repeat center;
    width:37px;
    height:37px;
    margin:0px auto 20px auto;
    display:block;
}

#home #content #twitter-main span.divider {
    border-top:1px solid #535353;
    height:0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#home #content #twitter-main h2.feed {
    margin:40px 0;
}

#home #content #twitter-main p.info {
    font-size:10px;
    color:#666666;
}
```

and JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    //HOME.PHP

    $('#top-slide').mouseover(function() {
        ('#select').fadeIn(600);
    });

    $('#top-slide').mouseout(function() {
        ('#select').fadeOut(600);
    });           

});​
```

This code brings up the following errors on mouse in and mouse out respectivley :

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #select has no method 'fadeIn'`

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #select has no method 'fadeOut'`

I thought it might be something to do with the mouseover / mouseout methods but tried it with click method also but it does the same.

I have probably done something silly but i cant find the issue.

Here is a JSFIDDLE for everyone: http://jsfiddle.net/Ze28y/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `$` into the handlers.

```
$('#top-slide').bind("mouseenter", function()
{
  $('#select').stop(true).fadeIn(600); //$('#select'), not ('#select')
});

$('#top-slide').bind("mouseleave", function()
{
  $('#select').stop(true).fadeOut(600); //$('#select'), not ('#select')
});
```

Also, you should add a `stop` first before your fades, [to prevent multiple fadein fadeouts to queue](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). And, because `#select` is a child of `#top-slide`, you should use the events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. (related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover))

Comment: wow thanks you must of read my mind because I just encountered a problem related to mousing into the #select element :) fixed it now

Answer (score 3):

try this, you missed `$`

```
  $('#top-slide').mouseover(function() {
        $('#select').fadeIn(600);
    });

    $('#top-slide').mouseout(function() {
        $('#select').fadeOut(600);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

use `$`

```
 $('#top-slide').mouseover(function() {
    $('#select').fadeIn(600);
});

$('#top-slide').mouseout(function() {
    $('#select').fadeOut(600);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `$` to declare a jquery object

Answer (score 2):

Missing $ and you've better to use hover.

```
$('#top-slide').hover(
    function() { $('#select').fadeIn(600); },
    function() { $('#select').fadeOut(600); }
);
```