# Using jquery on and hover events

Tags: jquery, hover

I have the following code, which causes an error below. How do I use JQuery on with hover correctly?

The code:

```
// Hover on the view filters
$('body').on('hover', '#viewfilter', function(event)
{
    $('#filterblock').show();
},
function(event)
{
    $('#filterblock').hide();
});
```

There is no error but the show part doesn't seem to be firing.

Comment: I don't think that error does has to do with `.on('hover'`.

Comment: Not *exactly* a duplicate of that, but close enough to be answered by it.

Comment: What version of jQuery is that? This is using 1.7.2 works fine http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/w2CeM/1/

Comment: Chris, please post more code so we can help you more.

Comment: You can't possibly be calling for multiple "viewfilters" using an ID. ID's cannot be re-used.

Also, whoever downvoted please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks ok, you can see the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/w2CeM/1/) Joe Buckle fixed with your code.

Your error must be in some other part of the code.

The only suggestion I have is that you use `mouseenter` instead, you can read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover) about it.

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to add the eventListener to multiple "view filters" using `'#viewfilter'`.

This isn't possible because `#` is the selector for `ID`'s. 
You can use a className and then call it using `'.viewfilters'`. This is probably the issue, but without more code it's impossible to be sure.