# Mouse events on any underlying div (without selecting class/id)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, mouseevent

I have one transparent div with `id=1`, and I need to pass mouse events to all underlying divs (regardless of class / id) while keeping this transparent div reactive to it's own mouse events.

So selecting underlaying divs by class/id, and `pointer-events: none` / `display: none` are not the options.

```
$('#1').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('background','rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.3)');
});
$('#a').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
$('#1').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('background','rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.2)');
});
$('#a').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).css('background', '#555555');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B6SAy/

How can this be achieved in a class/id independent way?

If it means anything, I have only 1 underlying div at the same time, but that div can have any class / id.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of mouseenter() and mouseleave(), you could try mouseover(), mouseout(), and/or hover(). These links may help:

[StackOverflow: Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)

[Ben Nadel: jQuery Events: MouseOver / MouseOut vs. MouseEnter / MouseLeave](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm)

You can also check out the documentation for each function at api.jquery.com.

Comment: how does help for lower level div ?

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining better adding the links to the functions' documentations.

Comment: OK, I added the links.