# Jquery animate not working with IE - nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any reason the following shouldn't work in any version of IE?

```
$(".scroll").mouseover( function () {
   $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10000);
});

$(".scroll").mouseout( function () {
   $('body').stop()
});
```

I've tested in 8-10 to no avail, but It's working perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari. I tried wrapping the contents in a div and animating that instead of `<body>` but still no luck - nothing happens at all.

Comment: Can you post your html code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set body and html as selector, some browsers have an issue if you use body only.

Comment: This worked - I changed it to: html,body instead of just body - working great. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` instead..

Here's why - [Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're either using jQuery version 2.x which dropped support for older IE browsers, or you're using an old version of jQuery 1.x. Try upgrading to the latest version of 1.x (1.10.2 right now). The [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/) explains more about the differences between the versions and has links to the minified JS files you can link directly hosted by MaxCDN.