# How do I change the opacity of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#logo').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#logo').fadeTo("fast",0.3);
  });

  $('#logo').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#logo').fadeTo("fast",1)
  });
});
</script>
```

I made this to change the opacity of an image while hovering over it with the cursor, but this doesn't happen. :(

Comment: Appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/NuK4G/. Need more context.

Comment: Please share the HTML part or a jsfiddle. Check the id of your img tag. Is that #logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that, you can use CSS:

Example HTML - you need it to have the ID `logo`.

```
<img id="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Example.svg/200px-Example.svg.png" />
```

CSS

```
#logo {
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
}

#logo:hover {
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter:alpha(opacity=30);
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pFEdL/2/

Answer (score 0):

What does you HTML look like for your image? Is it embedded in other divs?

[SO: Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)

As [gilly3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361684/gilly3) states in the question above, "Each time your mouse enters or leaves a child element, mouseover is triggered, but not mouseenter".