# MouseEnter vs MouseOver in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mouseevent

I was playing with AngularJS mouse events and got into a problem. I know ***MouseEnter*** event is fired when mouse enters container of an element and there after ***MouseOver*** is fired for all child elements.
Thanks to this animation [Visualizing mouse events](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5247027)

However turns out that in my case MouseEnter event is never fired. I  am working on Angular PhoneCat application (step-10) and did following modifications:

1. **Controllers.js**: Added a method to log mouse events
2. **phone-details.html**: Added *ng-mouseenter* and *ng-mouseleave* handlers

```js
    $scope.logMouseEvent = function() {
        switch (event.type) {
          case "mouseenter":
            console.log("Hey Mouse Entered");
            break;

          case "mouseleave":
            console.log("Mouse Gone");
            break;

          default:
            console.log(event.type);
            break;
        }
```

```html
<ul class="phone-thumbs">
  <li ng-repeat="img in phone.images">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-Click="setImage(img)" ng-mouseenter="logMouseEvent()" ng-mouseleave="logMouseEvent()">
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Result:

Only **mouseover** and **mouseout** event being logged

### Question:

Is this behavior happening because images are **ul** element and we are moving mouse in child elements? and How can I get **mouseenter** event on image?

Thank you 
[image]

Comment: Found the correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover

Answer (score 9):

Angular's ngMouseenter directive fires an event whose type is **mouseover**, as you can see in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/smivbBahFSqkb2ixUyaE?p=preview).

The difference from ngMouseover is that it's fired only once - when mouse enters the element, not after every movement within this element too.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
  <button ng-mouseenter="lastEventType=$event.type">
    Enter
  </button>
  Event type: {{lastEventType}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks @audonex, but that's what I was trying to understand. Why your plunker never show mouseenter event? If both events are same then why there are two events for the same purpose?

Comment: @Rohit I look at it the way that it's one event triggered by two different directives for two different purposes. There should be a reason why the type of mouseenter event is **mouseover**, but at the moment I can't think of any. IMHO there is nothing to understand, just accept the way it is. There should be no limitations caused by this.

Comment: "after every movement within this element too" - this is not correct, movement doesn't fire ng-mouseover. 
Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover