# Blinking when moving over h1 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which shows some text when hovering the image. But there is some problem when cursor is moving over h1 tag, It's blinking at that time. Why it's happening?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.content1').mouseover(function() {
    $('.content').show();
  });
  $('.content').mouseout(function() {
    $('.content').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <img class="content1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/2000px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" style="width:100%;position:relative">
  <div class="content" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; text-align: center; color: white; display: none; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.901961);">
    <h1 style="color:white">hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: ...and it happens in Chrome, just to add... (firefox is ok)

Comment: How is it blinking? Which browser? Fine here in ff and chrome

Comment: I can see it BTW. Using Chrome. Though it is quite subtle.

Comment: @nevermind me also using chrome..

Comment: It seems to be firing the mouseout function then immediately firing the mouseover.

Comment: mouseenter/mouseleave problem? Maybe due to margins or something on `h1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that when the mouse is over the `<h1>`, a `mouseout` is triggered on `.content`. To fix this, use `pointer-events: none;` for the `<h1>`. [Read about pointer-events on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

```
<h1 style="color:white; pointer-events: none;">hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</h1>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j3zqgsou/

Comment: @Pranav C Balan: Note: `pointer-events: none` is not available on legacy browsers.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is you're using "mouseover", this fires an event every time you switch containers with your mouse. for example, you can see this silly behaviour here :

https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

at the bottom.

This can be proven by using a simple CSS line :

```
h1{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Which makes the H1 tag completely transparent to the mouse.

Fiddle! 
https://jsfiddle.net/yy5afj0o/

Answer (score 1):

You can use following CSS to prevent it:

```
h1 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I also tried to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`.

This worked for me:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.content1').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.content').show();
  });
  $('.content').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.content').hide();
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvuj48yr/1/

Information: [Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)