# Jquery Toggle () on Hover

Tags: jquery, css

OK so I search and tried few examples but none of them worked. I am using Jquery `toggle()` to show a `DIV` on click. It works fine, except I want to show it on hover and keep it open if mouse pointer is inside the Div.

Here is my Code:

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#HCLink').click(function() {
        $('.HCContent').toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" id="HCLink">HEATING & COOLING | </a> </li>
<div class="HCContent" style="display:none;">
    <p>Div Content...</p>
</div>
```

Tried to change `.click` to `.hover` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this;

http://jsfiddle.net/redeown5/2/

you can use `mouseleave` event for parent element.

Comment: This works for Hover, but it hides when the mouse is out of the Div. Need to keep it open whenever the mouse is over the Div.

Answer (score 2):

Set the mousenter/mouseleave on container LI element, e.g using `hover()` in/out handler:

```
$("li").hover(function () {
     $(".HCContent").stop().toggle("slow");
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 0):

Use hide/show instead like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#HCLink').on('mouseover', function() {
        $('.HCContent').show('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('#HCLink').on('mouseout', function() {
        $('.HCContent').hide('slow');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/2b7xL51m/

Comment: Thank Brett, your code worked for Hover, but it hides as soon as the mouse is out of the Div. I need to keep the Div open. thanks

Comment: It will stay open until the mouse leaves the DIV, just like you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Take a look.

```
$("#HCLink").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $(".HCContent").show("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tk5rr4bb/1/

#### NOTE use `mouseenter` not `mouseover`

#### The reason why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286680/2956107