# How to fire event after 3 sec of hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div and I want to fire an event only after user continuous hovers his mouse for 3 sec. My code doesn't work well because it fires right after hover and doesn't "wait".

Code:

```
$(".inner_pic").mouseenter(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('testing');
    }, 3000);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    alert('finish');
});
```

Comment: Show more code. Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nn33vwvn/ seems to work to me. What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to store timeout id somewhere and clear it on mouseout. It's convenient to use data property to save this id:

```js
$(".inner_pic").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function () {
        alert('testing');
    }, 3000));
}).mouseleave(function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    alert('finish');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner_pic">PICTURE</div>
```

Comment: Fun note: With Internet Explorer 11 (maybe other browsers / versions) activating the alert then hovering over the alert with my mouse causes plenty more to open.

Comment: @ThePyroEagle Wow, this is very weird browser! Turns out that IE11 fires mouseout event in this case even though alert is on top, which would prevent subsequent interactions with the page. Strange quirk.

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this by `delay` option:

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7d70czt3/)

```
$('#elem').popover({
    trigger: "hover",
    delay: {show : 3000, hide : 0} });
```

Comment: Not in jQuery. There is no jquery `popover`.

Comment: @JonP, yes, you are correct. You can fire any event in jquery by simply changing `popover` . `popover` comes from bootstrap js library.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the below code

```js
var myVar;
$( "div#container" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
  });
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
div:hover {
  background: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Can you attach this to every container with a specific class rather than by id?

Comment: @SomaHoliday: Yes of course you can use **ClassName as a selector instead of an ID**.. 
just use `$("div.ClassName")`

Answer (score 2):

```js
    
    var st;
    $(".inner_pic").mouseenter(function(e) { 
        var that = this;
        st = setTimeout(function() {
            alert('testing');
        }, 3000);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
         clearTimeout( st );    
         alert('finish'); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner_pic">
  <h3>Picture Here - Hover me</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `div` with `id` of `myelement`, you can do this:

```
var divMouseOver;
$('#myelement').mouseover(function() {
  divMouseOver = setTimeout(function() {
     alert("3 seconds!"); //change this to your action
  }, 3000);
});
$('#myelement').mouseout(function() {
  if (divMouseOver) {
    clearTimeout(divMouseOver);
  }
});
```

BTW, tere's a helpful clarifying question re: using `mouseenter` and `mouseover` right here: [Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover).  Consider this when choosing which to use.

Comment: `divMouseDown` should be `divMouseOver` though.