# How to change CSS over selected element only using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it where when the user .mouseover() the .featured_products the .featured_products, and the .button will apply the CSS affect to the selected container. The problem i'm encountering is it changes the .css of both the .feature_products containers. I'd like it to only change the one that's being .mouseover(). I tried using $(this) but i'm not understanding it correctly.

```
$(".featured_products").mouseover(function(){
    $(".fp_button").css("background-color", "#00addc");
    $(".fp_button").css("color", "#FFFFFF"); 
    $(this).addClass("fp_hover");
  });
  $(".featured_products").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".fp_button").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".fp_button").css("color", "#000000")
    $(".featured_products").removeClass("fp_hover");
  });
```

Here is my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/4417zugn/30/embedded/result/)

Comment: is there a reason you're handling this with jQuery? Do you have access to the CSS?

Comment: Mostly because Jquery is the newest language i'm learning, so i thought it would be a easy way to achieve this affect. Could you give me a demo of the CSS alternative maybe on some simple <Div> boxes with background-colors? Thanks! :)

Comment: There: http://jsfiddle.net/4417zugn/36/ it's very simple CSS, I would avoid jQuery for that.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had no idea CSS had the ability to do something like this. I thought it was limited to by it's own element. I will use this alternative instead. Atleast i learned both ways to-do this. Thanks a bunch! Is this something new with CSS?

Comment: It's not new, but IE6 (I forgot about IE7) had trouble with :hover on anything else than an achor tag (`<a>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second parameter in the selector to denote a parent, like:

```
$(".fp_button", this).css("background-color", "#00addc");
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4417zugn/31/

---

You can also do something like:

```
$(this).find(".fp_button")...
```

etc. There are many ways.

One thing I'd suggest is to change the class name instead of modifying individual CSS rules, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4417zugn/33/

---

Last thing, this is all possible using only CSS, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4417zugn/35/

Comment: Thanks A bunch! This helped me a- lot understanding how to use the This function.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope I covered all relevant scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use jQuery to alter the CSS you can do that in the CSS itself using the :hover selector. You can then use jQuery to toggle the 'fp_hover' class.

```
$('.featured_products').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('fp_hover')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lozgnz84/

Comment: Why wouldn't you do the whole thing in CSS then?

Comment: Because it's not clear in the question what the 'fp_hover' class is being used for. It may not be for styling alone.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".fp_button")` is common for both the divs; so 
instead of writing:

`$(".fp_button").css("background-color", "white");`

Write:
  `$(this).find('.fp_button').css("color", "#FFFFFF");`

Hence, your code becomes

```
$(".featured_products").mouseover(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.fp_button').css({"background-color":"#00addc", "color":"#FFFFFF"});          
    $this.addClass("fp_hover");
 });
$(".featured_products").mouseleave(function(){
  $this.find('.fp_button').css({"background-color":"white", "color":"#000000"});
  $this.removeClass("fp_hover");
});
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/znnamrwn/

Answer (score 0):

What you've described can be done without jQuery. If however you would like to use jQuery you could simply toggle a class on the product element.

```
$('.featured_products').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fp_hover');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fp_hover');
    }
}, '.featured_product');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bradlilley/uwxsr4hu

---

You can also do the above without jQuery by simple adding the following hover state in your css.

```
.featured_product:hover .fp_button {
    background: #f00;
    color: #000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bradlilley/9mwxo9o2/6/

**Edit:** You should also avoid using mouseover and use mouseenter instead.

[Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)