# Text and border of svg acting like one element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, text

I am making a map area + svg interactive map. The svg part appears when I hover over big region like EU. But everytime I hover over text or border it disappear. Does anybody know how to solve this?

CSS:

```
   .eu {
    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;
    left: -80px;
    display: none;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1200px;
    z-index: 300;
    }

    .visible {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: all;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
    $('#eumap').mouseover(function () {
    $('.eu').addClass('visible');
    });
    $('.eu').mouseout(function () {
    $('.eu').removeClass('visible');
    });

    $('#apmap').mouseover(function () {
    $('.ap').addClass('visible');
    });
    $('.ap').mouseout(function () {
    $('.ap').removeClass('visible');
    });
```

There is too much svg to copy, so here is a little [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g04qhcw9/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your CSS...

```
text {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/g04qhcw9/

Answer (score 0):

> The svg part appears when I hover over big region like EU. But everytime I hover over text or border it disappear.

That’s because you are using mouseover/mouseout – they fire again each time you move the mouse over *child elements*. (See [Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover) for details.)

Simply use mouseenter/mouseleave instead:

```
$('#eumap').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.eu').addClass('visible');
});
$('.eu').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.eu').removeClass('visible');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g04qhcw9/1/