# Animate only once

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery .animate() to move an item once, but it seems to be moving in increments of 100px multiple times. Is it because of mouseover over?

```
var ww = $(window).width();

$(document).on('mouseover', '#myTarget', function () {
     var dp = $(this).offset().left;

     if ((ww - dp) < 150) {
         $('.myDiv.active').animate({left:'-=100px'},500);
     }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is because of the mouseover.

Comment: There seems to be no issue with your implementation. Check this out : https://jsfiddle.net/1hpfo1h7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing it to 
`$(document).on('mouseenter', '#myTarget', function () {`
would be better. Every time your mouse enters or leaves the element or one of its children, a `mouseover` event is triggered. This will not happen with `mouseenter`. The  [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/7/) shows this.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover) for a similar question and the source for the example provided.

Answer (score 1):

The mouseover event is sent repeatedly while the mouse is over the target.  You may want mouseenter and mouseleave

Answer (score 1):

Use [jquery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(document).one('mouseover', '#myTarget', function () {
  var dp = $(this).offset().left;

  if ((ww - dp) < 150) {
     $('.myDiv.active').animate({left:'-=100px'},500);
  }
});
```

Comment: .one() is neat, but I need to be able to call this function again, so in this particular case mouseenter may save the day. Thanks for recommending .one(), I've never used it but it has great potential.

Comment: Ok great, misunderstood your question