# Mouseover and mouseout trigger multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two on mouseover and mouseout events in JS. They are for checking wether I'm hovering over a panel on my page. But the problem is when I hover over a panel it triggers (good), but then when I hover over another element inside that panel it triggers a the mouseout event and then the mouseover events again when I move to another part inside the panel.

I only want the mouseover and mouseout events firing once! Once for entering the panel another for leaving it. Is there a way to propagate the on mouseover call to all child elements in the div.panel. It seems like that would correct it.

Here are my events

```js
$(document).off("mouseover").on("mouseover", "div.panel", function() {
   var panelSpaceId = $(this).attr("data-spaceId");
   var marker = _.find(scope.markers, function(item) {
     return item.spaceId == panelSpaceId
   })
   google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "mouseover");
   console.log("over" + marker.spaceId);
 });

 $(document).off("mouseout").on("mouseout", "div.panel", function() {
   var panelSpaceId = $(this).attr("data-spaceId");
   var marker = _.find(scope.markers, function(item) {
     return item.spaceId == panelSpaceId
   })
   google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "mouseout");
   console.log("out" + marker.spaceId);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 67):

You can avoid this issue by using `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`, and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`. The reason is simple: `mouseenter` is only fired when the cursor "enters" the element, which includes its children—so hovering over the child of the element does not re-fire the `mouseenter` event.

This similar logic applies to `mouseleave` vs of `mouseout`. You can see this effect happening [based on a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/7/) created by @gilly3 in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286680/395910) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover). I am not marking your question as duplicate because your answer is primarily troubleshooting `mouseover/leave` events instead of asking about the distinct between `mouseover/enter` and `mouseout/leave`.

It is helpful to imagine this:

- **entering** means when your cursor enters the bounds of the element. Even when you are in a child node, you are still **within the bounds**, hence it is never triggered multiple times.
- **(h)overing** can be visualised as seeing your element on a canvas. If the element you your cursor over is visible on the screen, the **mouseover** event is triggered. The cursor is no longer **over** the parent element when your cursor moves **over** the child element, hence when you go back and forth the event is triggered over and over again.

Here is your modified code, where I simply replaced the offending events with the right ones:

```
$(document).off("mouseenter").on("mouseenter", "div.panel", function() {
  var panelSpaceId = $(this).attr("data-spaceId");
  var marker = _.find(scope.markers, function(item) {
    return item.spaceId == panelSpaceId
  })
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "mouseenter");
  console.log("over" + marker.spaceId);
});

$(document).off("mouseleave").on("mouseleave", "div.panel", function() {
  var panelSpaceId = $(this).attr("data-spaceId");
  var marker = _.find(scope.markers, function(item) {
    return item.spaceId == panelSpaceId
  })
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "mouseleave");
  console.log("out" + marker.spaceId);
});
```

Comment: is there a way to reset the triggers in the events because they don't seem to work after I update the page with an ajax and re load these two events

Comment: @user1186050 That probably belongs to another question. However, I can see that you are binding the events to the document element, which shouldn't be an issue. I can't troubleshoot based on this information alone, you'll have to provide an MCVE for the purpose.

Comment: [**M**inimal, **c**oncrete, and **v**erifiable **e**xample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Terry, I posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645224/trigger-event-not-firing-after-ajax-call

Comment: I'm using mouseenter and mouseleave still it gets triggered multiple times in datatable rows...