# mouseenter() on two element creating jerk in sliding of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to bind `mouseenter` event of jquery on two different elements on event firing `div3` slide. But when cursor move from `div1` to `div2`,  `div3` first slide up and then slide down.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gzcnouux/

**Expected Behaviour**: `Div` only slide up when cursor is out of both the `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to accomplish this, but to illustrate the point, the `mouseleave` event is triggered before the `mouseenter` which causes the div to slide down and up.  You can do a simple check on the [relatedTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/).

```
if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.id != 'd2' && e.relatedTarget.id != 'd1')
    $('#d3').slideUp();
```

[ID Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzcnouux/1/)

A more maintainable way using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and its `contains` method.

```
if (e.relatedTarget && !e.relatedTarget.classList.contains('box'))
    $('#d3').slideUp();
```

[Class Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzcnouux/3/)

Comment: I was writing the same answer. You were faster :) Perfect answer. welldone.

Comment: @Sven, great ! Does this work on all browser? Can you update the answer for class as well, as I used id just for quick fiddle

Comment: @MatthewBarbara, typing speed always give you benifit ;)

Comment: @Master.Deep , use this for classes: `if(e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.className != 'd2' && e.relatedTarget.className != 'd1)'`

Comment: @Master.Deep, If your elements contains many classes you must to check if includes `d1` or `d2`. That can be achieved using `classList` and `includes` methods.`if(e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.classList.includes('d2') && e.relatedTarget.classList.includes('d1')`. `includes` is a feature of `ES6`.

Comment: @Master.Deep I've updated it for classes (assuming they all have the same class).

Comment: no they dont have. And sorry I don't have access to HTML

Comment: @Master.Deep without seeing the HTML, I can't help.  If there are few enough elements which won't be added/deleted or dynamically changed, you can use Alexandru-lonut Mihai's suggestion.  Otherwise, you need to find something else all the affected elements have in common.

Comment: The divs are located in one common div ?

Comment: I solved it with some changes. Thanks both for Help.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai , +1 for you too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mouseover` event.

You should bind `mouseover` event for `document` **DOM** element and `check` if is not `d1` or `d2`.

This can be achieved using `event.target` property in order to find out the **DOM** element that initiated the event.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', function(e) {
    if(e.target.id!='d1' && e.target.id!='d2')
       $('#d3').slideUp();
});
```

See [full](http://jsfiddle.net/gzcnouux/2/) working solution.

Comment: Whhy mouseover instead of mousenter

Comment: This is not mandatory for use  `mouseover`. This is how is works my example.

Comment: But see differences here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover

Comment: So as per that question mouseover fire inside the element as well if moved to child. while mousenter  take all as single event

Comment: @Master.Deep, yes, Each time your mouse enters or leaves a child element, mouseover is triggered, but not mouseenter.