# Using .animate and .mouseover to let an element appear/disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, mouseleave

I'm learning JavaScript and jQuery and while doing the following exercise I had a problem.
I have a div on the right side of the page which contains another smaller div, which contains an unordered list with some imgs, that I want to appear only when the mouse pointer enters the first div.

The problem is that when the mouse pointer enters the first div, the smaller one starts moving up and down uncontrollably.

I've tried using the .is(:hover) method on the bigger div, as suggested by another question on SO but it didn't help.

Here's my code:

```js
stato = "out";

$("#control").mouseover(

  function() {

    if (stato == "out")
      $("#socialBox").animate({
        top: 300
      });
    //$("#socialBox").show();
    stato = "in";



  }

);


$("#control").mouseleave(

  function() {
    $("#socialBox").animate({
      top: -500
    });
    //$("#socialBox").hide();
    stato = "out";

  }

);
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#control {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

#socialBox {
  position: fixed;
  top: -500px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 75px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control"></div>
<div id="socialBox">
  <ul>
    <li><img id="cane" src="img/cane.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img id="gatto" src="img/gatto.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img id="koala" src="img/koala.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img id="mucca" src="img/mucca.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img id="panda" src="img/panda.jpg" /></li>
    <li id="nascondi"> X </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've also tried using other mouse events such as mouseenter and mouseout but I get the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alex thanks for your editing: can you explane to me which changes did you apply to my code? I can't see any.. :-S Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the behaviour is triggered because the "#socialBox" enters the view, then blocks the "path" between mousepointer and "#control" and so the script triggers a mouseleave-event.

First of all, get rid of the mousemove... use mouseenter and you can delete the stato variable.

Next wrap the "#control" div around the "#socialbox" like so:

```
<div id="control">
  <div id="socialBox">
    <ul>
      <li><img id="cane" src="img/cane.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img id="gatto" src="img/gatto.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img id="koala" src="img/koala.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img id="mucca" src="img/mucca.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img id="panda" src="img/panda.jpg" /></li>
      <li id="nascondi"> X </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Thieri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9608144/thieri) mentioned, you need to wrap your `socialBox` inside of the `control` div.

The `socialBox` is not bound to the parent div.

---

```js
stato = "out";

$("#control").mouseover(
  function() {
    if (stato == "out")
      $("#socialBox").animate({
        top: 0
      });
    //$("#socialBox").show();
    stato = "in";
  }
);


$("#control").mouseleave(
  function() {
    $("#socialBox").animate({
      top: -500
    });
    //$("#socialBox").hide();
    stato = "out";
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#control {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

#socialBox {
  position: fixed;
  top: -500px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 75px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control">
  <div id="socialBox">
    <ul>
      <li><img id="cane" src="img/cane.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img id="gatto" src="img/gatto.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img id="koala" src="img/koala.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img id="mucca" src="img/mucca.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img id="panda" src="img/panda.jpg" /></li>
      <li id="nascondi"> X </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your animated `#socialBox` is not nested into `#control`. Whichever mouse event you're using, whenever the animating box gets under the cursor, the cursor "leaves" `#control`, triggering the hide animation.

If you want to keep your markup as it is, you can delay the animation with a timer. In my solution below, the timer makes sure that the animation will not be executed if both `#control mouseleave` and `#socialBox mouseenter` (or vice versa) trigger at almost the same time.

I also called `.stop()` before the animation to avoid queueing multiple animations by moving the mouse too quickly.

```js
var shown = false;
var timer;

function triggerAnimation(show) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // If we're already on the same state, no need to animate
        if (show === shown) return;

        // Animate socialBox
        $("#socialBox").stop().animate({ top: show ? 300 : -500 });

        // Toggle state
        shown = !shown;
    }, 10);
}

$("#control, #socialBox")
    .mouseenter(function() { triggerAnimation(true); })
    .mouseleave(function() { triggerAnimation(false); });
```

```css
body { background: lightblue; }
img { height: 50px; width: 50px; }
ul { list-style-type: none; }
#control { position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100px; background: yellow; }
#socialBox { position: fixed;  top: -500px; right: 0px; width: 75px; background:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control"></div>
<div id="socialBox">
    <ul>
        <li><img id="cane" src="img/cane.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img id="gatto" src="img/gatto.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img id="koala" src="img/koala.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img id="mucca" src="img/mucca.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img id="panda" src="img/panda.jpg"/></li>
        <li id="nascondi"> X </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Move your `socuialBox` div into the `content` div.

**Complete explanation**:
The problem is all because of event bubbling.

First, your html need to be changed as the `socialBox` div is outside of the `control` div the event fires repeatedly even while using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. So the `socialBox` is moved into the `control` div and used `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Second, the event bubbling. The problem still comes after the first step because of event bubbling.

**mouseover** - triggered when a mouse pointer is moved into an element. While moving over the child element, events of child elements gets fired and the event bubbles that causes the `mouseover` of the parent getting fired.

**mouseout** - same as `mouseover` but triggered when leaving the element.

**mouseenter** - triggered only when the mouse pointer gets into the element to which the event is bounded. Event will no bubble.

**mouseleave** - same as `mouseenter` but triggered when leaving the element the event bounded to.

To understand more clearly, refer these docs. [jQuery mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), [jQuery mouseout](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/).

[@gilly3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361684/gilly3) has a nice working fiddle to demonstrate the events in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)

```js
stato = "out";

$("#control").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#socialBox").animate({
      top: 100
    });
    stato = "in";
});


$("#control").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#socialBox").animate({
      top: -500
    });
    stato = "out";
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#control {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

#socialBox {
  position: fixed;
  top: -500px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 75px;
  background: red;
  pointer:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control">
    <div id="socialBox">
      <ul>
        <li><img id="cane" src="img/cane.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img id="gatto" src="img/gatto.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img id="koala" src="img/koala.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img id="mucca" src="img/mucca.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img id="panda" src="img/panda.jpg" /></li>
        <li id="nascondi"> X </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```