# Jquery mouseenter and mouseleave not firing properly on svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, mouseevent

I want to highlight elements with a outline when hovered.

Css -

```
.hovercss-element-hover {
    outline-style: solid !important;
    outline-color: red !important;
    outline-width: 1px !important;
    outline-offset: 0 !important;
    outline: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Javascript -

```
$("body").find("*").mouseenter(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass("hovercss-element-hover");
});

$("body").find("*").mouseleave(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass("hovercss-element-hover");
});
```

This works fine on all the elements except svg. mouseenter seems to fire as outline is visible but mouseleave does not fire and outline never goes away.

[JS FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/zicsus/k7t5d4rL/8/)

Note- I don't want to use css :hover as it does not fit my use case.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a sample of your SVG in the HTML? Also, it would make far more sense and perform a lot better to make the hover effect work in CSS alone; JS is not the best solution for this.

Comment: In SVG you mat want to try `stroke` instead of outline

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan here is the code - https://jsfiddle.net/zicsus/k7t5d4rL/8/ . I have to perform operation when elements are hovered and :hover will have propagation to parents and will end up outlining whole page.

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented: In SVG you mat want to try `stroke` instead of outline.

```js
// find elements
$("*").mouseenter(function(e)
{
 e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass("hovercss-element-hover");
});

$("*").mouseleave(function(e)
{
 e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).removeClass("hovercss-element-hover");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
/*
.hovercss-element-hover {
 outline-style: solid !important;
 outline-color: red !important;
 outline-width: 1px !important;
 outline-offset: 0 !important;
 outline: 1px solid red !important;
}*/

.svg-inline--fa.fa-w-16 {
    width: 10em;
    border:1px solid;
}

path.hovercss-element-hover{stroke:red; stroke-width:10}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-download fa-w-16" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="download" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
  <path fill="white" d="M216 0h80c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v168h87.7c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L269.7 378.3c-7.5 7.5-19.8 7.5-27.3 0L90.1 226.1c-12.6-12.6-3.7-34.1 14.1-34.1H192V24c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24zm296 376v112c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24V376c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h146.7l49 49c20.1 20.1 52.5 20.1 72.6 0l49-49H488c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24zm-124 88c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20zm64 0c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swapping `.mouseenter()` with `.mouseover()` and `.mouseleave()` with `.mouseout()`?

From personal experience, I have had similar trouble with row highlighting on tables. Not 100% on the why or how I just know the alternates work better.

This [SOF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover) has some good information on the difference between the events.

---

Updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/msk6L18o/ and dropped `e.stopPropagation();` highlighting becomes much smoother and your issue looks to be fixed. `e.stopPropagation();` was preventing the leave/out events from firing if the mouse rapidly left the element before the event could complete. If you're required to use `e.stopPropagation();` you could move it below the add/remove class functions to prevent the event from stopping before those functions ran.

Comment: adding e.stopPropagation(); below is still giving me same issue.

Comment: I tried removing e.stopPropagation() in main code but it's not working.

Comment: Tested the above fiddle in fire fox and chrome, and updated this (https://jsfiddle.net/ymw5ev8h/) fiddle to use the svg selector with stop prop and I'm not seeing the sticky border issue you were describing. Maybe you have another issue?